# Trouble with a script I am writing Mac Apple Management

Tags: macos, scripting, sh

I am a technician managing 10 Mac Computers. I do not have and MDM to manage them. I manage them manually and one by one... I have some of my Mac Computers that even putting them non Administrator, their managed account comes back to be administrator.

I am at the point where I will write a script to prevent them from falling administrator.

This is my script :

```
PASSWORD=$(echo U2FsdGVkX1+6JWRG1T9hsA/DIOfb2OZdXBf9uVcYTxY= | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -d -salt -pass pass:wtf)
echo $PASSWORD | sudo -u administrateur adminUsers=$(dscl . -read Groups/admin GroupMembership | cut -c 18-)
for user in $adminUsers
do
    if [ "$user" != "root" ]  && [ "$user" != "administrateur" ]
    then
        dseditgroup -o edit -d $user -t user admin
        if [ $? = 0 ]; then echo "Removed user $user from admin group"; fi
    else
        echo "Admin user $user left alone"
    fi
done
```

The encryption command works but my second command(line 2) can't take my variable $PASSWORD, I have this :

```
sudo: administrateur: command not found
```

The script get stuck at "administrateur" from line 2.

Comment: its not `administrator`? (Pardon my anglo-centeric view ;-) ) . Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with the line

```
echo $PASSWORD | sudo -u administrateur adminUsers=$(dscl . -read Groups/admin GroupMembership | cut -c 18-)
```

First, `$PASSWORD` isn't in double-quotes, so several special characters might cause trouble. Actually, `echo` has its own problems with special characters, so `printf '%s\n' "$PASSWORD"` would be much more reliable.

Except that `sudo` doesn't accept passwords over standard input, so the pipe won't work anyway.

Also, you can't do a variable assignment in a `sudo` command. Well, you can, but it's useless because it would make a subprocess as the other user, set the variable in that subprocess... and then exit the subprocess so the variable vanishes along with it.

And the order of evaluation is all wrong. The shell expands the `$( )` part *before* running any of the commands (and as the current user). So it expands to something like:

```
 echo pwgoeshere | sudo -u administrateur adminUsers=root administrateur
```

... which will tell `sudo` to run the command `administrateur` with the variable `adminUsers` set to "root". Not what you want at all.

But there's good news: `dscl` can read the group membership from any user account, so you don't need `sudo` or any of that. Just use:

```
adminUsers=$(dscl . -read Groups/admin GroupMembership | cut -c 18-)
```

On the other hand, `dseditgroup` *does* need special access to change group membership. What user is this script running as? If it's already running as `root`, it'll just work. If not, you could use `sudo` (with the complications of passing the password to that), or much simpler pass the admin credentials as arguments, with the `-u` and `-P options:

```
dseditgroup -o edit -u administrateur -P "$PASSWORD" -d "$user" -t user admin
```

Two more suggestions: use lowercase variable names (e.g. `password` instead of `PASSWORD`) to avoid conflicts with the various the various all-caps names with special meanings, and run your scripts through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) and correct the things it points out.